# Xcode 3.2.5: Make "Treat Warnings as Errors" and "Run Static Analyzer" both true for new projects

Tags: xcode, compiler-options, defaults

**The Problem**

Every time I create a new project in Xcode I have to go to **Project > Edit Project Settings** and navigate to **Treat Warnings as Errors** and **Run Static Analyzer** to turn them on. For the life of me I cannot seem to find out how to make this the default from now on.

**What I Have Tried**

Hunting through the menus. Google. Stackoverflow.com. A animal sacrifice in a graveyard at midnight (OK, I haven't tried that yet, but after this it is next on my list).

**The Question**

Is there a simple way of setting compiler settings for new projects?

Please don't tell me to upgrade to Xcode 4. I already have it (and have not explored to see if I can accomplish this task in it yet). I still will need Xcode 3 for a few months.

Whoops! Almost forgot -- thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to simply create a custom project template that had those settings enabled.  Create two new projects, change the settings in one - then do a diff on the project.pbxproj files for both to see how the settings occur in the project file.

Then find the existing project templates in:

**/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates**

Copy them into the local custom project template directory in your local Library:

**~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates**

(don't forget the space)

Then modify the project file in the project template to have the same changes you got out of the project diff before.

Comment: Thanks Kendall! I suspected that this would be the answer, but I was hoping for an easier way (you know like a setting somewhere that said make this the default!). I'll leave the question open for a while to see if someone knows any sneakier way. But since I suspect your way works I'll vote it up.

Comment: If you really, really want to you could also simply change the project templates in place at the /Developer... location.  Then you wouldn't have to select anything custom... but you'd lose those changes every time you updated XCode.  With 3 on the way out though perhaps you'd not have many updates to re-apply changes to...

Comment: Well looks like this is the way to go. Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it.